# Error in in-app purchases array Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, in-app-purchase

In my *buy.js*, I am first checking if the user has previously purchased my package. If not, I am calling the buy method to initiate the purchase.

I am currently getting the error:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined
    at Object.onLicenseUpdate [as success] (buy.js:52:45)
    at buy.js:1:397
```

**Screenshot of the array received in the console and the error:**

[image: **Screenshot of the array received in the console and the error.**]

**The following is the code with the problem:**

```
function onLicenseUpdate(response) {
        console.log("onLicenseUpdate", response);
        var licenses = response.response.details;
        var count = licenses.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          var license = licenses[i];
          purchasedPackages = licenses[i].response.details.sku;
          if (purchasedPackages == skuInit) {
            purchased = true;
          }
          addLicenseDataToProduct(license);

        }
        if (purchased == false) {
          buyProduct(skuInit);
        }
        //console.log("");
      }
```

**Complete Buy.js code:**

```
/*...google chrome's code...*/

/*CODE FOR IN-APP PURCHASES*/


var prodButPrefix = "btnProdID-";
var statusDiv;

function init() {
  console.log("App Init");
  //statusDiv = $("#status");
  //  getProductList();

}

/*******************************
INITIATE PURCHASE
******************************/
$("#xmas").click(function() {
  checkIfPurchased("xmas");
  localStorage.purchasedXmas2016 = true;
});
/*******************************/



/********************************
Get purchased items
********************************/
var purchasedPackages;
var purchased = false;
function checkIfPurchased(sku){
  var skuInit = sku;
  getLicenses();
function getLicenses() {
  console.log("google.payments.inapp.getPurchases");
  console.log("Retreiving list of purchased products...");
  google.payments.inapp.getPurchases({
    'parameters': {env: "prod"},
    'success': onLicenseUpdate,
    'failure': onLicenseUpdateFailed
  });
}

function onLicenseUpdate(response) {
  console.log("onLicenseUpdate", response);
  var licenses = response.response.details;
  var count = licenses.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var license = licenses[i];
    purchasedPackages = licenses[i].response.details.sku;
    if(purchasedPackages == skuInit){
      purchased = true;
    }
    addLicenseDataToProduct(license);

  }
  if (purchased == false){
    buyProduct(skuInit);
  }
  //console.log("");
}

function onLicenseUpdateFailed(response) {
  console.log("onLicenseUpdateFailed", response);
  console.log("Error retreiving list of purchased products.");
}
}



function getLicenses() {
  console.log("google.payments.inapp.getPurchases");
  console.log("Retreiving list of purchased products...");
  google.payments.inapp.getPurchases({
    'parameters': {env: "prod"},
    'success': onLicenseUpdate,
    'failure': onLicenseUpdateFailed
  });
}

function onLicenseUpdate(response) {
  console.log("onLicenseUpdate", response);
  var licenses = response.response.details;
  var count = licenses.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var license = licenses[i];
    addLicenseDataToProduct(license);
  }
  //console.log("");
}

function onLicenseUpdateFailed(response) {
  console.log("onLicenseUpdateFailed", response);
  console.log("Error retreiving list of purchased products.");
}



/******************
* Purchase an item
****************/


function buyProduct(sku) {
  console.log("google.payments.inapp.buy", sku);
  //var sku = "";
  google.payments.inapp.buy({
    'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
    'sku': sku,
    'success': onPurchase,
    'failure': onPurchaseFailed
  });
}


function onPurchase(purchase) {
  console.log("onPurchase", purchase);
  var jwt = purchase.jwt;
  var cartId = purchase.request.cardId;
  var orderId = purchase.response.orderId;
  console.log("Purchase completed. Order ID: " + orderId);
  getLicenses();
}

function onPurchaseFailed(purchase) {
  console.log("onPurchaseFailed", purchase);
  var reason = purchase.response.errorType;
  console.log("Purchase failed. " + reason);
}


/*******************************
Update UI Buttons
********************************/
if(localStorage.purchasedXmas2016 == true){
  var text = document.getElementById("xmas").firstChild;
  text.data = "purchased";
  document.getElementById("xmas").style = "border-style:none";
}
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "",
  "options_page": "options.html",

  "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "javascripts/background.js"
        ]
    },
  "description": "",
  "version": "4.0.4.1",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popups/popup1.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",

  "icons": { "16": "icons/icon16.png",
              "32": "icons/icon32.png",
           "48": "icons/icon48.png",
           "64": "icons/icon64.png",
          "128": "icons/icon128.png" },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ]

}
```

I also know that this is not the most efficient way. Is there a way I can store all the purchased SKUs in an array (or any other efficient ways)?

Comment: Why do you re-define the functions `getLicenses()`, `onLicenseUpdate()`, and `onLicenseUpdateFailed()` with identical, or nearly identical code inside the scope of `checkIfPurchased()`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen I've added my manifest.json and also pointed out where the problem seems to exist (code snippet). Could you please check it out and mention some methods to fix this efficiently? Thanks!

Comment: At a *guess*, based on the error text, the problem is in the line `purchasedPackages = licenses[i].response.details.sku;` It means `licenses[i].response` is undefined at the time the error occurs. What that data is will depend on what you are getting as a response from `google.payments.inapp.getPurchases()`.  If it was me, I would look at the console log of `response` to be sure I was using the right structure. Alternately, use the debugger and step through the program. Another way would be you can print a bunch of output to the console to track what the data is.

Comment: While the [Google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap#get-purchases) leaves quite a bit to be desired, the structure you are using is not what I would expect to receive. Beyond that, it would take fully functional code and looking at what the `response` actually was to determine what was wrong. If you want the question to be complete, then you could do something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); and include the output in the question.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks! I've added a screenshot of the array returned in the console. Could you check if the structure is wrong?

Comment: Please add the `response` data structure as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not an image. Images do not allow us to copy & paste the information. In addition, an image does not permit it to be searched based on the contents.  In general, text based information (data, code, errors) in text format <<< code/errors as an image <<<<< nothing.  Images should only be used, in addition to text format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text formatted data/code/error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `details` array, does not have a `response` property.  The array is already a list of Objects containing a `sku` property.

To decode the `response`, you will need your `onLicenseUpdate()` function to be more like:

```
function onLicenseUpdate(response) {
  console.log("onLicenseUpdate", response);
  var purchased = false;
  var licenses = response.response.details;
  var count = licenses.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var license = licenses[i];
    purchasedPackages = license.sku;
    if(purchasedPackages == skuInit){
      purchased = true;
    }
    addLicenseDataToProduct(license);
  }
  if (purchased == false){
    buyProduct(skuInit);
  }
  //console.log("");
}
```

Although, I would use `forEach` instead of `for`:

```
function onLicenseUpdate(response) {
  console.log("onLicenseUpdate", response);
  var purchased = false;
  var licenses = response.response.details;
  licenses.forEach(license=>{
    purchasedPackages = license.sku;
    if(purchasedPackages == skuInit){
      purchased = true;
    }
    addLicenseDataToProduct(license);
  }
  if (purchased == false){
    buyProduct(skuInit);
  }
  //console.log("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting this error now: 
`Error in event handler for (unknown): ReferenceError: addLicenseDataToProduct is not defined
    at Object.onLicenseUpdate [as success] (buy.js:57:5)
    at buy.js:1:397`

Comment: @I-Parliament, I'm glad I was able to help. That function, `addLicenseDataToProduct()` is not defined in the code that you provided. Given that the code you have provided is not your complete extension there is no way to help with that.  If you wish to address that issue, please create another question, but include more code. If you do create another question, it might be a good idea to include a link to this question to provide context.